# Creating a distinct list from a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

I have a range of values from D2 to BK33, and i would like to create a single list of distinct values from this range.  Is there a single function that will create such a list?

Comment: Do you want the list placed in some block of cells ???

Comment: Yes, preferably a list, but the location doesn't matter.  I'll say BN2:BN70

Answer (score 0):

Enter these two macros and run sub TESTU:

```
Sub ExtractUniques(rIn As Range, rOut As Range)
    Dim C As Collection, r As Range
    Set C = New Collection
    Dim cC As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In rIn
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            C.Add r.Value, CStr(r.Value)
        End If
    Next r
    cC = C.Count
    I = 1
    For Each r In rOut
        r.Value = C.Item(I)
        I = I + 1
        If I > cC Then Exit Sub
    Next r
End Sub


Sub TESTU()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("D2:BK33")
    Set r2 = Range("BN2:BN70")
    Call ExtractUniques(r1, r2)
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

1. The destination range is not cleared before the transfer
2. If there are more distinct values than space in the destination range, the destination range is filled and the extra distinct values are discarded.

**EDIT#1**

To meet the requirement to run the process if the data changes,

First discard sub **TESTU**

Second modify sub **ExtractUniques** to make it Public:

```
Public Sub ExtractUniques(rIn As Range, rOut As Range)
    Dim C As Collection, r As Range
    Set C = New Collection
    Dim cC As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In rIn
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            C.Add r.Value, CStr(r.Value)
        End If
    Next r
    cC = C.Count
    I = 1
    For Each r In rOut
        r.Value = C.Item(I)
        I = I + 1
        If I > cC Then Exit Sub
    Next r
End Sub
```

Third place the following **Event Macro** in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("D2:BK33")
    Set r2 = Range("BN2:BN70")
    If Intersect(r1, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    r2.ClearContents
    Call ExtractUniques(r1, r2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Is there a way to make this run continuously, or do i need to run it any time the values change?